# using an event listener to prompt a .load event

Tags: jquery, event-listener

I have a .load event that I'm trying trigger using an event listener.  I have a overlay that slides down, and when it finishes the animation I'm trying to use the jquery .load to load the contents of a url http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html into the overlay div.  I have a jfiddle set up but I can't seem to get it working, I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this, thanks.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rGhkH/6/

Comment: You have an extra `)`, use the jslint button. Also note, you can't `.load` cross-domain, therefore the code provided will never work in jsfiddle.

Comment: hmm checked that off and it didn't seem to change anything http://jsfiddle.net/rGhkH/7/

Comment: It changed a lot, it got rid of the error surrounding `)` and told you that you were prevented from making the ajax request due to the same-origin policy, which i explained in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the extra `)`, your code runs as it should considering what the code does.

```
var mybutton = document.getElementById("fullscreen_launch");
var fullscreen = document.getElementById("fullscreen");

mybutton.onclick = function() {
    fullscreen.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", function() {
        $('#fullscreen')
           .html('<img src="http://www.klossal.com/loader.gif"/>')
           .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
    });
    fullscreen.className = ' fullscreen_show';
};
```

Since `http://jsfiddle.net` is not the same domain as `http://www.klossal.com`, the browser restricts javascript from retrieving any information from `http://www.klossal.com` due to the same-origin policy. If this script was ran from `http://www.klossal.com` it would work.

Comment: this is driving me crazy, for some reason it doesn't work at all on my site.  When  have the pieces separate they work fine, but when I put them together like this they don't. When I have this listed inline: onclick="fullscreen.className = ' fullscreen_show';" and this listed as a script like this: <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#fullscreen_launch").click(function() {
        $('#fullscreen')
           .html('<img src="http://www.klossal.com/loader.gif"/>')
           .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
    });
});
</script> it works

Comment: the reason I want it as an eventlistener instead of onclick like this is because the animation doesn't run smoothly when it tries to load the ajax at the same time, so I wanted the animation to run and then have the ajax snag the content.  When I put the script together it doesn't even prompt the animation to happen.  It didn't in the jfiddle either.

Comment: What browser are you testing in?